# How do I get a car or motorcycle permanently?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to have a car or motorcycle in the same way I have a helicopter or a boat: permanently, even if I am busted, wasted, drive it into the river, blow it up, total it, etc.

Is this possible? I know the garages don't do this.

Is it possible to change the "default" player cars?

Comment: I generally only play multiplayer, though can't you insure it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I wouldn't know how to go about doing so even if it's possible.

Comment: As became clear in the answer, insurance is only available in multiplayer. As it stands, this is really a very annoying feature left in the game that I can't stand. What's the point in buying a $1,000,000 car if you're going to lose it at random when you die accidentally, or when a mission doesn't correctly respawn it?

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase insurance for the vehicle. If it is destroyed or lost in some way, you can pay a certain fee and they will give you a new duplicate car that you must go pick up. The fee is on average 1% of the total car cost.

Source: http://gta.wikia.com/Mors_Mutual_Insurance

> Mors Mutual Insurance **cannot be used in Grand Theft Auto V**, but gains a much larger role in Grand Theft Auto Online.

Comment: I think this is only true in multiplayer.